# How can I list all the databases of a PostgreSQL database server with RazorSQL?

Tags: postgresql, razorsql

I use [RazorSQL](http://razorsql.com/download.html) as an interface to my PostgreSQL database server, which contains three databases.

If I use pgAdmin, I can list all three databases (namely, `mimic`, `postgres`, and `pubmed`):

[image]

However, with RazorSQL, it seems that I have to specify the database when connecting:

[image]

As a result I only see the that the database I specified, e.g. `mimic`:

[image]

How can I list all the databases of a PostgreSQL database server with RazorSQL? I would like to graphically navigate between databases.

I use RazorSQL 6.3.14 with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: AFAIK the database name is a mandatory part of every JDBC connection string, therefore any client connecting via JDBC has to specify a database.  Still, if you are connected to one of the DBs in your cluster, you should be able to list all the databases - you can try this by running `SELECT datname FROM pg_databases`.  How and if this specific client is willing to list them graphically is another question.

Comment: @dezso Thanks, you are welcome to write an answer as it sounds like a good explanation. I was into trying to graphically navigate between databases.

Comment: @dezso actually, somehow DBeaver manages to list all databases even though it uses JDBC: http://i.stack.imgur.com/sv0Of.png   ->http://i.stack.imgur.com/5oLZs.png  But it isn't able to access them, except for the one that was specified in the connection settings: http://i.stack.imgur.com/HP3pN.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll summarize the answer that this question received in the comment section.
To be able to list all the databases of a PostgreSQL database server with RazorSQL, one has to first connect via JDBC to the PostgreSQL database server, which requires specifying a database.  Then one can run a command to list all databases.

---

Comment:

> - AFAIK the database name is a mandatory part of every JDBC connection string, therefore any client connecting via JDBC has to specify a database. Still, if you are connected to one of the DBs in your cluster, you should be able to list all the databases - you can try this by running `SELECT datname FROM pg_databases`. How and if this specific client is willing to list them graphically is another question.  [dezso](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/6219/dezso)
>    [Aug 22 '16 at 5:48](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/147404/how-can-i-list-all-the-databases-of-a-postgresql-database-server-with-razorsql#comment280623_147404)